# Microsoft LogParser: How to use parameters in a file

Tags: sql, logging, parameters, logparser

I have started to use Microsoft LogParser in order to analyse IIS logs.

LogParser allows using SQL query from a file and supply parameters to the query directly in a command line, for example:

```
LogParser file:query.sql?date=2010-12-29 -i:IISW3C
```

*query.sql* is a file name with SQL query

*date=2010-12-29* is a parameter that is supplied to the SQL query

Here is content of query.sql:

```
select cs-uri-stem
      ,count(*)
from logs.log 
where date = <date>
group by cs-uri-stem
```

The problem is that I don't know how to call  parameter in the file. Does anybody know this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the parameters in you query file like this

```
%VARIABLE_NAME%
```

So, in your example

```
select cs-uri-stem
      ,count(*)
from logs.log 
where date = %date%
group by cs-uri-stem
```